# What is the name of this variation: 1. e4 b6 2. e5?

Tags: opening, 1.e4

I had started playing Owen's Defense. My opponent pushed the pawn one step forward.

What variation did he try, securing this pawn he may play well.

```
r1bqkbnr/p1pppppp/1pn5/4P3/8/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 1 3
```

Comment: Please be more precise. Are you sure of the position?

Comment: Yep! 1.e4 b6 is Owen's defense

Comment: Ok. I know 1.e4, b6 is Owen's defence, but this is not the position you show, you have to add 2. e5,Cc6?! to obtain your position. This is not a king's gambit at all. Anyway, e5 is fully playable but maybe Cc6 is not the best. It blocks the c-pawn and the possible opening of the c-file for black heavy pièces (rooks and queen). Bb7 could also give you a full diagonal to exert direct influence on white's development and reduce white options. E5 is probably not bad but not best. Steinitz played such early e5 moves against the French defence, for instance, but with other ideas in mind.

Comment: An early e5 weakens white's control of the center and plays into black's hand somehow, if black plays correctly. There are many possibilities, you should try to investigate move by move with a computer or a stronger playing friend. (see Cleveland's answer)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the King's Gambit, that is 1.e4 e5 2.f4.

Comment: Yep! Understood.

Comment: 2.e5 is just a bad move.

Comment: I felt get resigned. Hence I remember I had opt out from the Game. Maybe my opponent didn't moved hence then. No idea what exactly had happened. But was curious to know what's that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea whether this line has a name. The plan is apparently to prevent the natural development of the knight from g8 to f6. Also black might struggle finding a good spot for the bishop on f8. On the plus side for black it opens the long diagonal a8-h1 for the black bishop.

Likely white is sooner or later going to support the pawn on e5 with d4 and f4, and black should somehow work against this strong center with moves like c5, d6,..

Therefore I think that 2. ... Nc6 is not the best move as it blocks the pawn on c7 and also the knight might get attacked later if white pushes the d pawn d2-d4-d5...

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that this variation has a name. Variations that are infrequently played are less likely to be named. I don't have access to Megabase right now, but I can't even find a game starting with 1. e4 b6 2. e5 in online databases. You're already well away from main lines with 1... b6. 2. e5 seems weird (2. d4 would be my choice) and 2... Nc6 will impede the bishop on b7.

Answer (score 2):

There is no King's Gambit here, which begins with `1. e4 e5 2. f4`

This opening looks OK for getting White out of his book, but otherwise I don't know what Black has going for it. This would be a fine blitz opening for Black since it's unusual. I don't care a lot for White's `2.e5`.

Stockfish finds nothing remarkable after the OP's moves.

Answer (score 1):

This is standard Owen's Defense, after your move to Nc6; white should play d4 for a strong center. In my opinion, your move to 2)...Nc6 is not the best; c5 to discourage d4, or d5 might keep your light squared bishop more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

French defense Steinitz attack starts with 1. e4 e6 2. e5. It's very likely that after OP's initial moves, e6 will be played. So it might transpose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it was b6 Owen's. Not French defense. However good to know about this varation. Thanks!